# Should I enable root account for rsync?

Tags: rsync, user-management

How can I enable the root account? I know it is not usually recommended but I'd like to setup a non-interactive script to backup my server using rsync. I could use `--rsync-path="sudo rsync"` but then I would need to store my sudo password in clear which seems much worse than enabling the root account.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Create new, separate `mybackup` user accounts on the client and server
2. Lock the passwords with `sudo passwd -l mybackup` for these accounts to prevent direct login
3. Allow, via `sudo`, those new accounts to run a very specific `/usr/bin/rsync/ --some-long-command /from/here /to/there` command as root with `NOPASSWD:` in `/etc/sudoers` using `sudo visudo`
4. Create new passwordless SSH keys for the local to the remote host using `sudo -u mybackup ssh-keygen`
5. Add to `sudo -u crontab -e` on one or other end to run the remote `rsync` using `ssh` and the keys as the transport

This way the only command that *can* be run as root is the one that you have explicitly allowed, and the only remote user that can activate it is the holder of the other half of the installed ssh keypair, which because it also has the password locked can only be somebody with sudo access themselves, or the crontab you set up.

Comment: That's exactly what I didn't think of allowing a very specific command in sudoers (I allowed 'rsync'). Great suggestion!

Comment: +1 for noting "a very specific ... command". Otherwise, giving a user the right to run `sudo rsync` and allowing the user to choose the options passed to rsync means that the user can use rsync to read/write the `/etc/sudoers` file for example, and grant himself full sudo access.

Answer (score 7):

1. You can edit `/etc/sudoers` to allow whatever user is running the command (or all users) to run it as `root` without a password (perhaps a bit dangerous with rsync).
2. Can't you just run the whole command/script/whatever as `root`? I assume this is going to run via cron so just add a `root` job via:

   ```
   sudo crontab -e
   ```

   Note: you can do fairly complex things by wrapping your cron command in a `bash -e "..."` brace or just do it in a separate script. Assuming it's not setuid'd, if `root` runs it (through `cron`), it will run as `root` so that should solve your permission issue.

Comment: The problem is that if I setup the script on my local machine and run it as root, it will have permission problems on the server. If I setup the script on my server and run it as root, than the local machine will be the one with permission problems. In other words, I need to have root privileges on both the local and server machines.

Comment: You could write a script at each end and allow it to be run with `sudo` by normal users. That would be safer than just allowing `rsync`.

Comment: Sudo is a great idea. You can specifiy precisely, which user can run which command. Do it.

Answer (score 6):

You could (but should not) give the root user a password with

```
sudo passwd root
```

Edit: Setuid bit does not work for scripts.
Otherwise, you could use the setuid bit on the backup program.

```
sudo chown root backup
sudo chmod u+s backup
```

Maybe, you even want to run the backup as a cron job?

Comment: You don't need to specify "root" since sudo runs as the root's env its user *is* root. (`sudo whoami` returns, root) so just `sudo passwd` is needed.

Comment: setuid doesn't work for scripts

Comment: Right, scripts are executed by the shell named in the she-bang line. Sorry for the misinformation.